# How to deploy a laravel project in ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu

I have installed laravel files in ubuntu ec2 instance. Now when I reload my web page, It is showing all the directories but not the laravel page. 
Following are the steps that I have performed to make project run on web page:-

1) Installed laravel project inside /var/www/html/pma (pma being the project name)

2) sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/pma/storage

3) cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

4) sudo nano laravel_project.conf

5) Add the following to create the new Virtual host with server’s IP address.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://13.126.105.89/
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pma

<Directory /var/www/html/example>
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

6) sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf

7) sudo a2ensite laravel_project

8) sudo a2enmod rewrite

9) sudo systemctl restart apache2

These are the steps I have performed, but still web page is showing the directories not actual laravel web page. What am I missing in this?

Comment: config your public folder also

Comment: I believe you have to point both `DocumentRoot ...` and `<Directory ...>` to `/var/www/someproject/public`. The `public` directory is fairly important since it defines the location of the `index.php` file

Comment: @Flame okay, I'll do that. I have now run command php artisan serve --host=13.126.105.89 --port=80 to deploy the web page. After this I am receiving error that 'illuminate foundation application' not found in /var/www/html/project/bootstrap/app.php.

Comment: just as a sidenote `php artisan serve` uses the `server.php` file in your root dir and its not suitable for production environment

Comment: @Flame okay, then how can i make my project running.

Comment: with a proper webserver like apache